# How to use If statement in Flutter widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new in flutter and practicing simple app. But now, I can insert one line conditional statement but I want to add If statement. So I can add more statement. How do I do that? Here is my code. Please have a look. I want to add more color when I reach targeted amount **color: _moneyCounter > 1000 ? Colors.green : Colors.red,**

```
Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  '\USD $_moneyCounter',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: _moneyCounter > 1000 ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
                    fontSize: 40.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can so multiple ternary operators :

```
_moneyCounter > 1000 ? Colors.green : _moneyCounter > 2000 ? Colors.Blue : Colors.red
```

But for readability i don't recommend doing this so you can use a function that will return the color :

```
Color getMyColor(int moneyCounter) {
 if (moneyCounter == 1000) then {
    return Colors.green;
 } else
  if (moneyCounter == 2000) then {
   return Colors.red;
  }
}
```

and then use that function :

```
color: getMyColor(_moneyCounter),
```

Comment: Hello Sir @Raouf Rahiche, Thank you so much but could you please complete the Return Method. So I can follow

Comment: check the answer again

Answer (score 9):

You can use different widgets as below,

```js
Column(
    children: [
        if (_id == 0) ...[
          Container()
        ] else if(_id == 1)...[
          Text("Hello")
        ] else ...[
          SizedBox(height: 20)
        ],
    ],
 ),
```

Comment: Didn't see that in the documentation. Saved me a ton of time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you use in Column

```
Column(children:[  if (e["index"] == 1)
              Text(e["text"].toString(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green[900])),
            if (e["index"] == 2)
              Text(e["text"].toString(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
            if (e["index"] == 3)
              Text(e["text"].toString(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber)),
            if (e["index"] == 4)
              Text(e["text"].toString(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange)),
            if (e["index"] == 5)
              Text(e["text"].toString(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
          ])
```